# Python3.8 imports _io whenever importing anything

Tags: python, python-3.8

I want to track which imports are being done when importing a module. (The goal is to forbid importing harmful modules, but that is not the point of this question.) For MCVE purposes, let's say I do it like this:

```
import builtins
orig_import = builtins.__import__


def new_import(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args[0])
    return orig_import(*args, **kwargs)


builtins.__import__ = new_import

import my_module
```

In Python ≤ 3.7, this works as expected and prints `my_module` as well as all the modules that `my_module` imports (and recursively all modules that these modules import). However, in Python 3.8.0, I get the following output *even if* `my_module` does not import anything:

```
my_module
_io
_io
```

Where did the two `_io` lines come from? I have tried looking in the docs, but could not find anything useful.

Comment: Printing `args[1]['__name__']` reveals the module `_io` is actually called `_frozen_importlib_external`. Not sure where to go from here however.

Comment: I saw a question with funny 3.8 behavior when mocking a certain module function a few hours ago, maybe it's related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897718/how-to-patch-the-python-3-breakpoint-builtin/62106849#62106849